# HTML Special Character ▼

Tags: html, special-characters, html-entities

Is there an HTML Entity for special character ▼ ?

Answer (score 7):

Feed that character to the [search of fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) and you get the page of [Unicode Character 'BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE' (U+25BC)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm) which says among others:

> HTML Entity (decimal) `&#9660;`

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, just using that character *directly* in the HTML source shouldn't be a problem if you just save the HTML source file as UTF-8 and set the `charset` attribute of the HTTP `Content-Type` header to `UTF-8` as well. This way you don't need to fiddle with HTML entities.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the entire HTML set, if you're interested:

> ▲ = &#9650;
>
> ▼ = &#9660;
>
> ◄ = &#9668;
>
> ► = &#9658;